# Why does "slabtop -o" only return the first 23 lines when the command is piped?

Tags: linux

I was trying to parse the output of `slabtop -o` with awk to compute the sum of the cache size, but when the output is piped it only returns the first 23 lines. I tried this on Ubuntu and Centos.

```
# slabtop --version
slabtop from procps-ng 3.3.10
# slabtop -o | wc -l
23
```

Why does it only return the first 23 lines when the command is piped ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slabtop`, even with `-o`, [always limits itself to one screenful of output](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/f9a8009e27d47a61096ff7bf1de37a90f0f801e6/slabtop.c#L414). It normally does so by asking the terminal what its size is, but when its standard output isn’t a terminal, [it assumes that the screen is 80 columns by 24 rows](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/96c524990b1ec3ceeac249360b7654a8988f5912/slabtop.c#L168) and only outputs 23 rows (to avoid any scrolling).

This [since has been fixed](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/0ef497bb350c4a1b6a872029a3050ce8250466de), and the fix is present in `procps-ng` 3.3.13 and later.

Answer (score 2):

It's just hard-coded to work this way when output isn't a terminal.

if you still want to use redirection and get more rows, you can use `script` to trick `slabtop` into thinking it's output is being printed to the terminal. You can add `stty` on top of that to change pseudo-terminal parameters and set your own limit for output lines.

```
# slabtop -o | wc -l
23
# script -q -c "slabtop -o" /dev/null | wc -l
46
# script -q -c "stty rows 999; slabtop -o" /dev/null | wc -l
147
```

Alternatively, you can just get your information directly from `/proc/slabinfo` file, which is also used by `slabtop` itself.